# How to get list of groups the user is associated with in Azman?

Tags: active-directory, active-directory-group, azman

I'm able to get the roles associated with the authenticated user but not the groups. Is there a way to get the groups

```
WindowsIdentity userIdentity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as WindowsIdentity;

AzAuthorizationStoreClass azManStore = new AzAuthorizationStoreClass();

string storeConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["<CONN STRING>"].ConnectionString;

azManStore.Initialize(0, storeConnectionString, null);

IAzApplication azApp = azManStore.OpenApplication("<APP NAME>", null);

ulong token = (ulong)userIdentity.Token;

IAzClientContext ctx = azApp.InitializeClientContextFromToken(token, null);

object roles = ctx.GetRoles(String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a way.  On my project we had one requirement for this and ended up doing a simplistic implementation that walked through each Group and checked if the user was a member.  The problem with this approach is that it ignores membership via groups in groups and also membership via the user being a member of an AD group that is a member of the AzMan group.  You could grow the solution to cover these scenarios, but ultimately I think that when you start asking questions like this, you might be heading down the role-based security path with Azman (which is operation (or task) based security).